# Visual Studio Code: how can I import the `sbt`-changes

Tags: scala, visual-studio-code, sbt, scala-metals

After adding another dependency in `build.sbt` - how can I import the `sbt`-changes?

With the Command *Reload Window* it works but it reloads everything (like `bloob`).

Is there a way just to just import the `sbt`-changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metals extension supports natively [importing sbt changes](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html#importing-changes)

> When you change `build.sbt` or sources under `project/`, you will be
>   prompted to re-import the build.

[image]

We can also manually import the changes by executing `Metals: Import Build` [command](https://scalameta.org/metals/docs/editors/vscode.html#manually-trigger-build-import).

---

Without Metals perhaps try [Send text from a keybinding](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_send-text-from-a-keybinding) to terminal which executes sbt `reload; update` by navigating to `View | Command Palette | Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` and defining the following, say, `cmd+shift+R` shortcut:

```
[
    {
        "key": "cmd+shift+R",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
        "args": {
          "text": ";reload; update\u000D"
        }
      }
]
```

`cmd+shift+R` should now just reload sbt changes instead of reloading whole Visual Studio Code window.

Comment: thanks - strangely I cannot edit this file (Cannot edit in read-only editor)

Comment: Where is it stored? To find the path, try right-clicking it and `Reveal in Finder` on the macOS or `Open Containing Folder` on Linux.

Comment: that does nothing - also no entry in the "problem tab" - I also checked the documentation but could not find anything useful

Comment: If it helps, on my machine, it is at `/Users/mario_galic/Library/Application\ Support/Code/User/keybindings.json` and it has permissions `-rw-r--r--`, so you could try `chmod 644 /yourpath/keybindings.json`

Comment: thanks - the key binding is now listed - but nothing happens - does it maybe miss the "when" part?

Comment: I checked another 'user' keybinding works without 'when'

Comment: @pme Please see edited answer. Try with Metals extension.